# How can I make a text box is optional if something entered in another text box?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This is my form where I must accept either phone number or email, ID or passport number

[image: 1]

What can be the logic to check the validation in js/ajax?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: A couple of `IF` statements obviously o.O

Comment: Please add your attempts.

Comment: make google your best friend, my friend

Answer (score 0):

`btnsubmit` click put one condition to validate please find my snippet for more information.

```js
$(".btnsubmit").on("click",function(){
  if($(".email").val() == "" && ($(".phone").val() == "" || $(".southafricanid").val() == "") && ($(".passport").val() == "" || $(".birthdate").val() == ""))
    {
     alert(); 
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Email :- <input type ="text" class="email" /><br/>
Phone:<input type ="text" class="phone" />
South African ID: <input type ="text" class="southafricanid" /><br/>
Passport : <input type ="text" class="passport" />
Birth Date :<input type ="text" class="birthdate" />
<br/>
<input type ="button" class="btnsubmit" value="Validate" />
```